# Maximum Adjacency Matching

Tags: graph-theory

I am having difficulties understanding what an adjacency matching according to the definition given in a paper.

> An adjacency matching in an undirected graph G is a collection of
>   disjoint edge pairs in G such that if two edges e and e' are paired,
>   then e and e' share a common endpoint. A maximum adjacency matching
>   is an adjacency matching with the maximum number of edge pairs.

Could anyone explain what an adjacency matching is according to this definition?

Comment: Do you understand the idea of a collection of disjoint pairs?

Comment: Nope. Had trouble there too. This is what I think though. If we include two edges (as a pair) in the matching, then we can't include either of these edges in any other pair (or matching). Is that right?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Now you are only allowed to use edges that are distinct from one another, yet share one endpoint, to make as many "disjoint pairs" as possible.  That's a maximum adjacency matching, as defined in your quoted paper.

Comment: Oh! Maximum is the most number of "disjoint pairs" that can be formed. Cool, thanks hardmath!

Comment: It would make your Question a little bit better to cite (give title and author) the paper where this definition is found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, an *adjacency matching* is defined for a simple undirected (finite) graph $G$ to be a disjoint collection of unordered pairs of (distinct) edges which share exactly one endpoint.  Therefore an edge of $G$ can belong to at most one such pair in the collection.

Then a *maximum* adjacency matching is one that has the largest possible number of edge pairs.  Finiteness of $G$ guarantees that the maximum number of pairs is attained by some adjacency matching.